# How to configure option "Launch webservice" in eclipse kepler?

Tags: eclipse

I did upgrade my eclipse standerd (Kepler) to Eclipse EE (Kepler). Normally in Eclipse EE, there is an option "Launch webservice" under Run. But my eclipse is not showing that. Do i need to install any plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know logic behind it but after restarting my ubantu (not only eclipse) issue got resolve !